# add pagination to "for each" loop in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Im just wondering is it possible to use the `pagination_links()` function in a `foreach` loop in wordpress?
When I try it nothing happens, I have looked around and it seems this is a little trickier than I was expecting...

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 6, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
   <div class="events">
        <div class="newslistingblock">
        <div class="newslistingblockheader"><p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="newslistingblockthumbnail">
         <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'news-thumb', $attr ); ?> </div>
         <div class="newslistingexcerpt">
                <?php the_excerpt( ); ?> </div> 
  </div>
  </div>



<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Im basically looking for basic pagination, with "next", "prev" and numbers.

Any help on this would be great thanks.

EDIT:
I have decided to change the code to this to suit wordpress...

```
    <?php 
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );
if (have_posts()) : 

while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<!-- Do suff -->

   <div class="events">
        <div class="newslistingblock">
        <div class="newslistingblockheader"><p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="newslistingblockthumbnail">
         <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'news-thumb', $attr ); ?> </div>
         <div class="newslistingexcerpt">
                <?php the_excerpt( ); ?> </div> 
  </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?> 
   <div class="navigation">
    <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('← Older Entries') ?></div>
    <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries →') ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: when posting the code try to post a full block!! In your posted code i cant see where you close your `foreach`..

Comment: Where do try to echo your pagination (and end your foreaqch, for that matter)?

Comment: See what's in $post with `var_dump` / `print_r` and do it yourself :)

Comment: apologies Deepak, I just editted it there

Comment: @Esben, I would want the pagination links to appear straight after the for each loop(which ive just editted in btw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `foreach` instead of `while`?

The default loop with pagenation should look like this (should work with foreach as well):

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <!-- Do suff -->
<?php endwhile; ?>    
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('← Older Entries') ?></div>
    <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries →') ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This just shows the `next` and `previous` link, but if you want pagination with numbers, I would suggest the great plugin: [Wp-Pagenavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/).

Good luck!

EDIT:

The error you are experiencing is that you haven't set the paged variable correctly. You need to do the following:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

query_posts('posts_per_page=5&paged=' . $paged); 
?>
```

Then everything should work.

You can find more information in the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query

Comment: Thanks Krycke, I changed the code (as seen above), but unfortunately, even though the next/prev appear, they dont really work, in that the same page with the same posts keep loading.

Comment: Agree - WP-pagenavi is one of the default plugins I put in just about every installation. Excellent, and easy to style.

Comment: hi, Ive installed wp_pagenavi and even though it showed up correctly, the actual navigation seems to keep going back to page.1 Any help here would be great thanks, heres the link...
http://limerickfc.hailstormcommerce.com/cms/?page_id=885

Comment: Edited solution for your problem above.

Comment: Thanks Krycke, that sorted it, Im going to read that link now to get a better understanding of what I actually did