# Add pagination to custom loop on a static page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to add pagination links or even next and previous page links to a static homepage on wordpress that is using a custom loop that I am not familiar with. I have very little php / wordpress codec knowledge and can't figure out how to achieve this. Below is the entire code for the loop and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also, it appears this is a child theme of the twentyeleven wordpress theme.

```
    <?php

    global $post;

    //$args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'category' => 7 );

    //$args=array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'category' => -6 );



    $myposts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); 

    //echo "<pre>";

    //print_r($post);

    ?>

  <div class="post_blog">
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
      <?php the_title(); ?>
      </a></h1>
    <div class="clr"> </div>
    <?php //the_date();?>
    <div class="post_cont">
      <div class="post_thum"> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
        </a> <span class="post_slogn"><?php echo $cfs->get('post_slogen'); ?></span>
      </div>
      <div class="post_right">
        <p>
          <?php //content(120);
          content(100);
          //the_content("Continue reading " . the_title('', '', false)); 
          //content('<p style="text-align: justify;"><!--more--></p>');
          ?>
        </p>
        <div class="clr"> </div>
        <span class="read_entry"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">MORE <span>»</span></a> </span>
        <div class="share"> <span class='st_facebook' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'></span><span class='st_twitter' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'></span><span class='st_linkedin' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'></span><!-- <span class='st_email' st_title='<?php //the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php //the_permalink(); ?>'> --></span><span class='st_plusone' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'></span><span class='st_fblike' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
 <div class="sub_title">
          <?php //the_tags(' ');
            the_tags('', ' ', ' ');

          ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the wordpress codex you will find there is a call for [next and previous posts links.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link)

```
 <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Name of your next post link', TRUE); ?>
 <?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Name of your previous post link', TRUE); ?>
```

In addition, you should [read this exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641251/add-pagination-to-for-each-loop-in-wordpress?rq=1) on how to implement pagination in a wordpress loop.